# GIMP script-fu to change editor UI

Tags: scheme, gimp

Can you change the general GIMP UI using script-fu (add buttons, etc, not only in the script-fu dialog, but directly in the editor), or at least create a more direct way to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Script-Fu and the API it uses are intended to not allow this.

Comment: Why is it designed this way?